# What is a module over an algebra in the category theoretic sense?

Tags: abstract-algebra, category-theory, modules, monoidal-categories

Can someone please confirm this for me. In category theory one defines monoidal categories. One can then consider monoids in a monoidal category $C$. Given such a monoid $M$, one can then consider modules over $M$. We have:

- In the Cartesian monoidal category $Set$:

  monoids are ordinary monoids, and modules over a monoid correspond to monoid actions.
- In the (non-Cartesian) monoidal category $Ab$ of abelian groups, with
  the tensor product of abelian groups:

  monoids are (unital) rings, and a module over a ring $R$ corresponds to the usual notion of $R$-module in algebra.
- In the monoidal category $R$-$Mod$ of $R$-modules (in the usual
  algebraic sense), with the tensor product of $R$-modules:

  monoids are (unital associative) $R$-algebras. **My question is**: what is a module (in the categorical sense) over an associative unital algebra $A$? Is it the usual "module over an algebra" which sometimes crops up in algebra, e.g. in [A module over an algebra. Is it a vector space?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/708113/a-module-over-an-algebra-is-it-a-vector-space) ?

Thanks

Comment: [Lawvere theory](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/Lawvere+theory) might be the key word.

Comment: @Bumblebee hmm I don't really see how this is relevant (but I may be mistaken; if so please let me know). I think this is just a different generalisation of the notion of an $R$-module, in a more categorical-logic direction. From what I can tell, algebras over a Lawvere theory are analogous to modules over a monoid (in a monoidal category), but this doesn't help in answering my question.

Answer (score 2):

If you want a really general category theory definition of a module, here you go:

A module over a $k$-linear small category $A$ is a functor from $A$ to $k$ vector spaces $A \to k\mathrm{-Vect}$.

This also naturally extends to modules over other small categories.

Now if you have a $k$-algebra $B$ it is actually a $k$-linear category with one object $$ and endomorphisms of $*$ are $B$, then a module over $B$ as a functor is the same as the classic definition of a module, just as geoffrey said! (which is a nice exercise)

A nice benefit of that is that you can carry over a lot of structures from vector spaces via this interpretation!

Answer (score 0):

For an $R%$-algebra $A$, an $A$-module is just a module over the underlying ring of $A$. The $R$-module structure on $A$ does not matter.

Comment: So modules over an $R$-algebra in the category-theoretic sense *do* agree with the usual meaning in algebra (as in the link I put in the question)?

Comment: Also, if I recall correctly (I read the start of a book on representations of algebras at some point), the fact than an $A$-module is a module over the underlying ring of $A$ does not make the $R$-module structure on $A$ totally useless.

For example if $R = K$ is a field (and so $A$ is an algebra over a field) then an $A$-module $V$ is, as you say, a module over over the underlying ring of $A$. however we can consider the embedding $K \ni \lambda \mapsto \lambda \cdot 1_{A} := \bar{\lambda}$, and then $V$ inherits a $K$-vectorspace structure by $(\lambda, x) \mapsto \bar{\lambda} \cdot x$.